# Controllers and Classes does not compile when publishing ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 to write a MVC 4 application. I'm writing C# code and I'm using Framework 4.5. My OS is Windows 7. I have published and deployed the application on local server many times without any problem. But now  I change some code in my controllers. It works fine when I debug my application. But when I publish my application and deploy it in localhost it seems that the changes have not been applied in the published versions. For example if I have an error and I fix it and debug it, it works but when I publish my application the error still exists. Another thing is that some portion of my code works fine in debug mode but not in published mode. This line is one of them.

```
RFH_ComplexRoomReserve firstRoom = db.RFH_ComplexRoomReserve.Where(d => (d.FKComplexRequestID == complexRequest.PKComplexRequestID)).First();
```

I searched a lot but could not find any solution. I think I'm making a dummy mistake. Any help is appreciated in advance.

**UPDATE:**

My MVC 4 web project name is MyWeb. As I know when I build my solution MyWeb.dll file is created in bin directory in my project directory. When I publish my project MyWeb.dll file is created in bin directory of publish folder. I noticed that these two files have different sizes. The .dll file that is inside the project directory is bigger than the .dll file of publish directory. When I replace MyWeb.dll file that is in publish folder with MyWeb.dll from project folder, everything works fine. I think threre is something wrong with publishing process. But I cant find it out.

Comment: try to restart VS....it may work

Comment: Are you sure you're publishing to the correct folder on the server, i.e. where your virt directory is pointing to? Also, is there error the same as before you published the new version? Also, is the publish 'deleting all files before publish' radio button selected?

Comment: Please change the publish target location path, then move this  published code into your virtual directory. OR Please clean your solution before publish the website.

Comment: Arun: I have restarted my VS several times. christiandev: yes. I publish my project directly into the folder that I have created in inetpub/wwww

Comment: @Beginner, try deleting the files first, refresh the page so you see 'resource not found' or whatever you have, and then republish

Comment: @christiandev, did not help

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Did you fixed it? I have a exactly problem here. looks like a bug....

Comment: @qakmak: The problem fixed. As far as I remember there wasn't a clean solution to my problem. I cleaned the solution several times. And ReBuilt the solution. As you mentioned it looks like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

> when I publish my application the error still exists

This can of course mean a few things. First make sure your publish actually does publish something. It might help to remove and re-create your publish profile if it doesn't. Also verify you are looking at the same directory to where you're publishing.

Comment: I delete the old files and then publish my app. I can see that the published files are regenerated again.

Answer (score 0):

If i were you i may try following options

1. Make sure i publish to right directory ( check timestamp of published app dll etc)
2. Reset IIS
3. Recycle AppPool
4. Clear Cache of IE

Answer (score 0):

When deploying to remote server, change Configuration-type to `Release`.
Goto `Build` -> `Configuration Manager` -> `Active solution Configuration` -> Change `Build` to `Release`, save then
 `Right-Click` on project -> `Publish`

Answer (score 0):

I have found the same problem repeatedly, but randomly occurring when publishing my project to the live server.  The views publish fine, but the controllers do not get updated.
The solution I have come up with is to change the code in a way that causes it to be recompiled but also in a way that doesn't actually change the way the code works.
For example, Before:

```
 if (model == null) return HttpNotFound();
```

After:

```
if (model == null || false==true) return HttpNotFound();
```

I then publish to the production server and the controller is compiled as expected and published successfully.

I then go back and remove the 'false==true' code afterwards, so that I don't leave garbage like this throughout my code.

I have tried the other suggestions here and so far this is the only sure way to fix this bug.  I'm using VS2015u3, C#/MVC5, publishing to IIS on Server 2008 R2.